# Comparing entwined powers of squares

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, radicals, maxima-minima, number-comparison

Compare the following numbers:
$$a=2016^{\sqrt{2014}}, b=2015^{\sqrt{2015}},c=2014^\sqrt{2016}$$
The answer to it was the following:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}\ln(x-1)- \sqrt{x}\ln x$$
defined for any
$$x\in[2;\infty)$$the function has a local maximum, strictly positive in a point with the abscissa $x_1\in(62;63)$, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$ and is strictly decreasing on the interval $[x_1;\infty)$, so it's also strictly positive on the interval. Applying the exponential we get $f(2015)>0$ which is $c>b$.

The function $$g(x) = \sqrt{x}\ln x - \sqrt{x-1}\ln(x+1)$$, 
defined for any
$$x\in[2;\infty)$$ has a strict positive local maximum in a poit of abscisa $x_2\in(45;46)$, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$$ and it's strictly decreasing on the interval $[x_2;\infty)$, so it's also positive on this interval. So $f(2016)>0$ which means $b>a$.

So c>b>a.

I see the logic of it. But my question is how on earth did the author find $x_1$ and $x_2$, the two local maximums of the functions? I've calculated the derivative and it's horrible. Please give some light! Thank  you!

Comment: I suspect a typo. More than likely it is $b=2015^{\sqrt{2015}}$

Comment: Yes. Thank you, @Claude Leibovici. Do you have any ideea how to find those maximums?

Comment: Numerical methods only. Plot the drivative, locate more or less a root and start Newton method. It would be quite fast. $62.6702$ comes from WA.

Comment: Your $g(x)=-f(x)$.  You probably want $g(x)=\sqrt x \log x - \sqrt{x-1}\log(x+1)$

Comment: Let me reformulate the question. How does he evaluate the sign of the derivative? And from that the sign and  monotony of the function?

Comment: Becuase the derivative is awful. What do you think @ClaudeLeibovici?

Comment: Thank you, @RossMillikan! What are your thoughts about the sign of the derivative?

Comment: Not so awful ! Just type  **extrema of  y=sqrt{x+1} ln(x-1)-  sqrt{x} ln x** in WA. You will get the result.

Comment: If this was in a competition, it was an awful question!